# Searching for characters between two delimiters in a string

Tags: python, html, string

I'm trying to parse a string to find all of the characters between two delimiters `<code>` and `</code>`.

I have attempted using regular expressions, but I can't seem to understand what is going on.

my attempt:

```
import re
re.findall('<code>(.*?)</code>', processed_df['question'][2])
```

where `processed_df['question'][2]` is the string (this string is continuous, I typed it into multiple lines for readability):

```
 '<code>for x in finallist:\n    matchinfo = 
 requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/{}".format(x)).json() 
 ["match_id"]\n    print(matchinfo)\n</code>'
```

I have tested with this test_string:

```
 test_string = '<code> this is a test </code>'
```

and it seems to work.

I have a feeling it has to do with special characters within the characters between `<code>` and `</code>`, but I don't know how to fix it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I don't see `</code>` in that sample string.

Comment: I apologize, I accidentally removed it upon cutting and pasting. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your might be better of with an html parser than regex

```
import lxml.html

html_snippet = """
 ...
 <p>Some stuff</p>
 ...
 <code>for x in finallist:\n    matchinfo = 
 requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/{}".format(x)).json() 
 ["match_id"]\n    print(matchinfo)\n</code>
 ...
 And some Stuff
 ...
 another code block <br />
 <code>
    print('Hello world')
 </code>
 """

dom = lxml.html.fromstring(html_snippet)
codes = dom.xpath('//code')


for code in codes:
    print(code.text)

 >>>> for x in finallist:
 >>>>     matchinfo = 
 >>>> requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/{}".format(x)).json() 
 >>>> ["match_id"]
 >>>>    print(matchinfo)

 >>>> print('Hello world')
```

Comment: Would this solution work if there are multiple code blocks in the html snippet? I'm trying to capture multiple code blocks within a single string and extract features from each section of code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is the newline \n character, just make sure to match using the `DOTALL` flag such as

```
import re
regex = r"<code>(.*)\<\/code>"

test_str = ("<code>for x in finallist:\\n    matchinfo = \n"
    " requests.get(\"https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/{}\".format(x)).json() \n"
    " [\"match_id\"]\\n    print(matchinfo)\\n</code>\n")

re.findall(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL)

'for x in finallist:\\n    matchinfo = \n requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/{}".format(x)).json() \n ["match_id"]\\n    print(matchinfo)\\n'
```

Comment: `DOTALL` alone is enough.

Comment: @blhsing, noted and removed.

Answer (score 1):

So the question doesn't explicitly say it needs `regular expresions`. With that said, I would say not using them is best:

eg

```
test_str = '''
<code>asldkfj
asdlkfjas
asdlkf
for i in range(asdlkf):
    print("Hey")
    if i == 8:
        print(i)
</code>
'''

start = len('<code>')

end = len('</code>')

new_str = test_str.strip()[start:-end] # Should have everything in between <code></code>
```